# Java: Stopping sound playback with button

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to get this sound stop when a button is pressed. Below is my play function. I have the button all set up I just need to give it something to do...Thanks!

```java
void play() {

       try {  
           URL url2 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("tone.wav");
           AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url2);
           Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

           clip.open(audioIn);
           clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
       }catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }finally{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Java Audio, `Clip` inherits from [`DataLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html) which has a `stop()` method.  According to the document for [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop%28int%29): If playback is stopped during looping, the current loop status is cleared; the behavior of subsequent loop and start requests is not affected by an interrupted loop operation.

So you would need to keep a reference to the `clip` object somewhere and use that in your buttons `onClick()` method.